# Form Validation To Send Only If Username Doesn't Exist

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I've created a JQuery script that checks a database for usernames and shows an error if you type in an existing name on keyup, this is workng fine but the form still submits even if this error is true.  What other code can I add to check that this error doesn't exist?  Here is the code I have so far:

```
<script>
        $(function()
        {
        var ck_username = /^[A-Za-z0-9_]{5,15}$/;
// Username validation
        $('#username').keyup(function()
        {
        var username=$(this).val();
        if (!ck_username.test(username))
        {
        $('.usernameStatus').removeClass("success").addClass("error");
        }
        else
        {
        $('.usernameStatus').removeClass("success").removeClass("error");
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'check-users.php',
                data: 'username='+ username,
                cache: false,
                success: function(response){
                    if(response == 1){
                        $('.usernameStatus').removeClass("success").addClass("error");
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.usernameStatus').removeClass("error").addClass("success");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        });
// Submit button action
        $('#registerButton').click(function()
        {
        var username=$("#username").val();
        if(ck_username.test(username))
        {           
            jQuery.post("register.php", {
            username:username,
            },  function(data, textStatus){
            if(data == 1){
            window.location.replace("registered.php");
            }else{}
            });
        }else{
        alert("Something went Wrong - Please Check All Fields Are Filled In Correctly");
        }
        return false;
        });
        //End
        });
        </script>
```

Thank you

Comment: So the alert "Something went wrong" is never showing?

Comment: Given that your php script does not modify the db, just gets results, it should be a GET. (I just learnt this today, thought I'd share :-))

Comment: The alert doesn't show, I'm guessing that I have to add something to "if(ck_username.test(username))" to make sure that the username hasn't been found - Possibly by adding something to the IF statement???

Comment: @ravloony POST is fine. POST and GET are just two different HTTP methods and it has nothing to do with modifying databases.

Comment: POST : Requests that the server accept the entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the web resource identified by the URI. The data POSTed might be, as examples, an annotation for existing resources; a message for a bulletin board, newsgroup, mailing list, or comment thread; a block of data that is the result of submitting a web form to a data-handling process; or an item to add to a database. -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods

Comment: So actually, POST means : here is some data, add it to this resource please.

Comment: In this instance, register.php is right for POSTing, but check-users.php should be a GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see the comments on the code 
assuming that the `data == 1` means that the name is already registered and you will show an error

```
<script>
        $(function()
        {
        var name = false; // a variable that holds false as the initial value
        var ck_username = /^[A-Za-z0-9_]{5,15}$/;
// Username validation
        $('#username').keyup(function()
        {
        var username=$(this).val();
        if (!ck_username.test(username))
        {
        $('.usernameStatus').removeClass("success").addClass("error");
        }
        else
        {
        $('.usernameStatus').removeClass("success").removeClass("error");
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'check-users.php',
                data: 'username='+ username,
                cache: false,
                success: function(response){
                    if(response == 1){
                        $('.usernameStatus').removeClass("success").addClass("error");
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.usernameStatus').removeClass("error").addClass("success");
                        name = true; // on success , if the name isnt there then assign it to true
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        });
// Submit button action
        $('#registerButton').click(function()
        {
        var username=$("#username").val();
        if(ck_username.test(username) && name == true) // check for the value of name
        {           
            jQuery.post("register.php", {
            username:username,
            },  function(data, textStatus){
            if(data == 1){
            window.location.replace("registered.php");
            }else{}
            });
        }else{
        alert("Something went Wrong - Please Check All Fields Are Filled In Correctly");
        }
        return false;
        });
        //End
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the username against the regex, you should check the status of `$('.usernameStatus')` because it is possible that it passes the regex test but still fails the duplicate test returned from your db.

So

```
$('#registerButton').click(function()
        {
        var username=$("#username").val();
        if(ck_username.test(username))
        {
```

should instead be:

```
$('#registerButton').click(function()
        {
        var username=$("#username").val();
        if(!$('.usernameStatus').hasClass('error'))
        {
```

Even better would be to introduce a variable that holds the validity of the name field so you don't need to get the DOM Element all the time and check it's class.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error might be because of a bad `data` syntax

It should be like this:

```
data: 'username:'+ username,
```

Debug your PHP code to see if its receiving the username properly at the moment though

Comment: Thanks I will do that just to make sure, It has been working OK so far but it's better to be safe than sorry, thank you